# Closed form solution to matrix geometric series

Tags: linear-algebra, time-series

Is there a closed form solution to the infinite sum
$Q + AQA' + AAQA'A' + \ldots $ ?

Note: I'm assuming here all eigenvalues of the square matrix $A$ are less than one.

Comment: What is $A'$? Inverse? Conjugate transpose? Both?

Comment: @TheoBendit conjugate transpose

Comment: @TheoBendit, I used the notation to mean transpose $A^T$. The question comes from a time series problem in which I am looking for the variance of a forecast at an infinite horizon for the model $x_t = A x_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ where $Q$ is the variance matrix for shocks. $x_t$ is a vector of observables.

Comment: It seems I'm not cool enough to edit my question, so this is going in as a comment: Defining the sum of the first $k$ elements as $S_k$ and element $k$ as $M_k$ we have, $S_1 + M_2 = AS_1A^T + Q$,  $S_2 + M_3 = AS_2A^T _ Q$, $\ldots$ so that the limit as $k \rightarrow \infty$ is $S_\infty = AS_\infty A^T +Q$ ... which I'm not sure helps since I can't isolate $S_\infty$.

Comment: This might help:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348487/solving-matrix-equations-of-the-form-x-axat-c

Answer (score 0):

@echasnovski, that's perfect, thanks so much!

Just to recap:

Defining the sum of the first $k$ elements as $S_k$ and element $k$ as $M_k$ then

$S_1 + M_2 = A S_1 A^T + Q$

$S_2 + M_3 = A S_2 A^T + Q$

so that as $k \rightarrow \infty$

$S_\infty = A S_\infty A^T +Q$

The solution to this equation can then be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348487/solving-matrix-equations-of-the-form-x-axat-c)